# Parse string to number in C

Tags: c

I tried to write a function to convert a string to an `int`:

```
int convert(char *str, int *n){
    int i;
    if (str == NULL) return 0;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
        if ((isdigit(*(str+i))) == 0) return 0;
    *n = *str;
    return 1;
}
```

So what's wrong with my code?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I guess you want to convert a string to an integer? The code you have written, as @dualscyther points out, mixes different memory buffer sizes without any good justification. Have a look at the `atoi()` function or its equivalents.

Comment: You need to more carefully define what you mean by "convert `char *` to `int *`".  Do you have a pointer to some characters, except that the characters are really the bytes making up some ints, and you want to access the ints?  Or do you have a pointer to some characters which are a string full of digits like `1` `2` `3` which are the decimal representation of an integer, and you want to convert the string to the corresponding integer 123 (and then somehow end up with a pointer to that integer)?

Comment: I'll try it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`*n = *str` means:
Set the 4 bytes of memory that `n` points to, to the 1 byte of memory that `str` points to. This is perfectly fine but it's probably not your intention.

Why are you trying to convert a char* to an int* in the first place? If you literally just need to do a conversion and make the compiler happy, you can just do `int *foo = (int*)bar` where `bar` is the `char*`.

Sorry, I don't have the reputation to make this a comment.

Comment: Your proposed change is undefined behavior on systems with more strict integer alignment than character alignment and generally does not make sense.  Also what is so weird at setting the value of an integer to the value of a char?

Comment: A widening conversion throwing a warning? Never had that.

Comment: Hm interesting, I guess I thought that the compiler would care with the appropriate warnings on. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

The function definitely does not perform as intended.

Here are some issues:

- you should include `<ctype.h>` for `isdigit()` to be properly defined.
- `isdigit(*(str+i))` has undefined behavior if `str` contains negative `char` values. You should cast the argument:

  ```
  isdigit((unsigned char)str[i])
  ```
- the function returns `0` if there is any non digit character in the string. What about `"-1"` and `"+2"`? `atoi` and `strtol` are more lenient with non digit characters, they skip initial white space, process an optional sign and subsequent digits, stopping at the first non digit.
- the test `for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)` is very inefficient: `strlen` may be invoked for each character in the string, with **O(N<sup>2</sup>)** time complexity. Use this instead:

  ```
  for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
  ```
- `*n = *str` does not *convert* the number represented by the digits in `str`, it merely stores the value of the first character into `n`, for example `'0'` will *convert* to `48` on ASCII systems. You should instead process every digit in the string, multiplying the value converted so far by `10` and adding the value represented by the digit with `str[i] - '0'`.

Here is a corrected version with your restrictive semantics:

```
int convert(const char *str, int *n) {
    int value = 0;
    if (str == NULL)
        return 0;
    while (*str) {
        if (isdigit((unsigned char)*str)) {
            value = value * 10 + *str++ - '0';
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    *n = value;
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

conversion of char* pointer to int*

#include

main()

{

```
 char c ,*cc;

 int i, *ii;

  float f,*ff;

  c = 'A'; /* ascii value of A gets 

  stored in c */

   i=25;

    f=3.14;

    cc =&c;

     ii=&i;


     ff=&f;

      printf("\n Address contained 

      in cc =%u",cc);

      printf("\n Address contained

       in ii =%u",ii);

       printf(:\n Address contained

       in ff=%u",ff);

       printf(\n value of c= %c",

       *cc);

       printf(\n value of i=%d",

       **ii);

       printf(\n value of f=%f",

       **ff);

       }
```

Comment: Formatting is horrible, won't compile. You should fix that and add some kind of explanation of what you're code is supposed to be doing and why.

Comment: Actually I at present I have no laptop that's why I use mobile application  4 ths purpose